# How can show data from another form

Tags: c#, winforms

This is basically a tic tac toe game, and I have another form called Winner.cs when a player wins I want it to call the form (this part works) and then I want it to say xWinner.label =b1.text"" + has won the game!. the part I cant get to work is displaying the text in the winners form label. There's an example of a message box that commented out for reference
instead of b1.text

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace MyGame
{
    public class Result1
    {


        static private int[,] Winners = new int[,]
                   {
                        {0,1,2},
                        {3,4,5},
                        {6,7,8},
                        {0,3,6},
                        {1,4,7},
                        {2,5,8},
                        {0,4,8},
                        {2,4,6},
                   };
        static public bool CheckWinner(Button[] myControls)
        {
            bool gameOver = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                int a = Winners[i, 0], b = Winners[i, 1], c = Winners[i, 2];
                Button b1 = myControls[a], b2 = myControls[b], b3 = myControls[c];
                if (b1.Text == "" || b2.Text == "" || b3.Text == "")
                    continue;
                if (b1.Text == b2.Text && b2.Text == b3.Text)
                {
                    b1.BackColor = b2.BackColor = b3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCoral;
                    b1.Font = b2.Font = b3.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 32F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Italic & System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((System.Byte)(0)));
                    gameOver = true;
                    Form xWinnerForm = new xWinnerForm();
                    xWinnerForm.Show();

                    //MessageBox.Show(b1.Text + " .... Wins the game!", "Game End", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                    //break;
                }
            }
            return gameOver;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is create your own `Show` method in your cWinnerForm class:

```
public void Show(string text)
{
    this.myLabel.Text = text;
    this.Show();
}
```

then you would have to change two lines of code in your code block:

from this:

```
Form xWinnerForm = new xWinnerForm();
xWinnerForm.Show();
```

to this:

```
xWinnerForm xWinnerForm = new xWinnerForm();
xWinnerForm.Show(b1.Text);
```

Another option is to pass the text into the xWinnerForm's constructor.

Comment: Or just add a Method "SetWinnerText(string text) {this.myLabel.Text = text; } and then call it with xWinnerForm form = new xWinnerForm(); form.SetWinnerText(b1.Text); form.Show();

Comment: I tried this method but it gives an error xWinnerForm.Show(b1.Text);  cannot convert from string to system.windows.forms.string iwin32window

Comment: @Michael Quiles: Mind posting the line of code that is throwing that error?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like b1's textbox is private (or protected).  Making it public should do the trick.

If the only thing that you want from b1 is the winner's name, each form in winforms has a Tag, which is public.  You can set the Tag after someone wins to the winner's name and then in the other form do b1.Tag.ToString() to get it there.

Also, as an aside; In a "real life" application you'd probably want to encapsulate some of these components into different classes rather than having forms look at each others' controls.

**EDIT**

I don't have Visual Studio in front of me now, but I believe that in the properties window you can set that particular textbox to "public."